# Hover over whole div

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm developing a website where you can post and get likes, replies, etc... whenever users posts it stores it in a div that I created, and in it, I have a section where likes, comments and share button are, I will show with the image. When I hover over likes, comments, or share it doesn't hover the whole section as I want, it covers half of it.

Here is my **index.html** code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="confessId" name="confessId_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" />
<div class="actions">
    <div class="likes">
        <span class="label label-confess first liked">
            <a href="" id="likeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="likeIt_<?php echo $count; ?> text-success">
                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                <span id="likesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['totalLikes']; ?>
                </span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="dislikes">
        <span class="label label-confess disliked">
            <a href="" id="dislikeIt<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>" class="dislike_<?php echo $count; ?> text-danger">
                <span id="dislikesVal_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                <?php echo $row['totalDislikes']; ?></span>
                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <?php if ($row['hasImage'] != '0') { ?>
        <span class="label label-confess"><i class="fa fa-picture-o img"></i></span>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="comments">
        <div class="divide">
            <a href="page.php?page=view&confession=<?php echo $row['confessId']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                <?php echo $totComments.' '.$comText; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divide2">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $set['siteName']; ?>%20Confession:%20<?php echo ellipsis($row['confessText'],65); ?>%20&url=<?php echo $shareURL; ?>" class="btn btn-tw btn-sm" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $twitterShareTooltip; ?>">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color:white"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And my CSS:**

```
.actions {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .1);
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.action {
    color: #DEDEDE;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 144px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
}

.confession .likes, .confession .dislikes {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .1);

    width: 144px;
}

.likes, .dislikes {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}


.divide{
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, .1);
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    color: #FEFEFE;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.divide2 {
    border-right: 0;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    color: #FEFEFE;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.likes:hover, .dislikes:hover, .divide:hover,.divide2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}


.divide a {
    color: white;
}
.confession .likes .label a, .confession .dislikes .label a { font-weight: 700 !important; }
```

I hope you guys understand me, thanks in advice.

Comment: Can you strip out the PHP parts of your code and wrap the demo in a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to replace margin by padding in the section `.likes`, `.dislikes {}` of your CSS. The issue is occurring only on top and bottom of your div, so I guess these margins are causing this.

Padding will add an "inner margin" whereas margin will add an "outer margin" that will not be altered when you hover.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped like a charm!